# Why do I keep seeing Lightning as a Ravager, when she's a Commando?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I've been looking for information on Lightning's role. I'm only about halfway through the game, but I was under the impression you had to buy Lightning in order to play with her.

I keep seeing YouTube videos of her fighting as a Ravager, but when I purchased and won her character, she's only a Commando.

How do I unlock the Ravager role for Lightning?

Answer (score 8):

There are two different Lightnings you can unlock [via DLC](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_XIII-2_Downloadable_Content):

- Lightning as part of the *Operation XIII-2* Coliseum battle, which is a Ravager and is almost always the Lightning people talk about in guides and such.
- Lightning as part of the *Another Beginning Lightning's Story: Requiem of the Goddess* DLC, which is a Commando.

It appears you purchased the latter DLC but not the former. It's odd that you can unlock two different Lightnings, but that's what paradoxes get ya.